# C# separate arguments and pass it to Process.Start() method

Tags: c#, process

I need to pass to my concole application several parameters:

1 Project Name

2 Version Name

3 Deployment Environment Name

4 Some Boolean

5 Array of integers

As far as I know, i need to run following code:

```
  string myParams = "Test proj name " + "3.22.652.965863 " + "QA " + "true " + "463841";
        //string cParams = "true ";
        var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\\ MyFolder\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe", myParams);
```

Whereas `MyExe.exe` entry point has this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(args[0]));

        string projectName = null;
        string buildNumber = null;
        string deploymentEnvironmentName = null;
        bool shouldResolve = false;
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();


        if (args.Length >= 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Arg: {i} is {args[i]}");
                    projectName = args[i];
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Arg: {i} is {args[i]}");
                    buildNumber = args[i];
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Arg: {i} is {args[i]}");
                    deploymentEnvironmentName = args[i];
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Arg: {i} is {args[i]}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Boolean convertion: {args[i]}");
                    shouldResolve = Convert.ToBoolean(args[i]);
                }
                if (i > 3)
                {
                    ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(args[i]));
                }
            }
            MyService.MyMethod(ids, projectName, buildNumber, deploymentEnvironmentName, shouldResolve);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You should define arguments only in following order: Project Name, Build Number, Deployment Environment Name and Array of your Change Sets");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I don't know beforehand how many integers I am going to have, but I need to know the order of other parameters in advance.
However my problem that `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method separates arguments through empty spaces. This means that my first parameter "Test proj name " will not be converted to one argument, but it will be parsed as "Test", "proj" and "name". It messes my code and I can't count on order of argument in advance.
How can I fix it?
Maybe I can define my own separator and ignore empty space as separator?
I will appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Normally 1 parameter containing spaces, should be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fix this problem by enclosing the argument in doublequotes:

```
string myParams = "\"Test proj name\" " + "3.22.652.965863 " + "QA " + "true " + "463841";
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A single argument that includes spaces must be surrounded by quotation marks, but those quotation marks are not carried through to the target application.

i.e. your application will receive `Test proj name` string without quotation marks around it.

Comment: This is that I missed!
Thank you!